# How to do a three column grid with bourbon neat?

Tags: sass, bourbon

I'm trying to create a three column grid, and have the columns evenly distributed across the row.

My markup is simple:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>
```

My scss is also pretty straight-forward.

```
 .row {
    @include outer-container ;
  }
 .service {   
    @include span-columns(4) ;
}
```

However the result is a mess:

[image]

That's close to what I want. But the blocks are all over the place.
They aren't evenly distributed either horizontally or vertically.

What could be going on here?
How can I get a simple three-column grid with even distribution of blocks?

Comment: Can you add which version of neat you are using? You likely need to clear the 3rd grid object. try http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#omega

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use the `omega` mixin here. Try this:

```
.row {
    @include outer-container ;
  }
 .service {   
    @include span-columns(4);
    @include omega(3n);
}
```

Some more information here:

http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#omega