# How do I create a three-column grid with neat?

Tags: bourbon, neat

I've had this question answered previously here:
[How to do a three column grid with bourbon neat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42218310/how-to-do-a-three-column-grid-with-bourbon-neat)
However, since I updated bourbon and neat on my system, that method no longer works.

Again, my markup looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>
```

And my scss looks like this:

```
.row {
    @include grid-container;
        .col {
            @include grid-column(4) ;
        }
    }
```

And the result looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lZHx.png

In previous versions this staircase issue could be fixed by using the omega mixin.

However, with the current version, if I include 'omega(3n)' sass returns "no mixin named omega".

If I go to the docs for the current version I can see that there is no information on 'omega' anymore. The changelog for 2.0 states that omega has been removed.

So, with the current version of neat: how can I create a three-column grid?

Comment: Not sure if reading through this will solve the problem but you might want to check [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat/issues/502) link.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I know is to put the first three columns in a .row div and the last three columns in their own .row div. That way you have two grid-containers, which creates a clear-fix.

Markup:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS (unchanged):

```
.row {
    @include grid-container;
        .col {
            @include grid-column(4) ;
        }
    }
```

Or, you could put a clear left on every 4th .col div.

Markup (only one "row"):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.row {
    @include grid-container;
        .col {
            @include grid-column(4);
               &:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
                  clear: left;
            }
        }
    }
```